# Extracting the URL of an external link to use as a constant

Tags: typo3, typoscript

I have defined some external links to store URLs to which other pages can link to. This way a change of URL by a backend user is reflected sitewide.

I wish to extract these URLs to text to put them them into a newsletter as that would be a better practice than redirecting through the site. How could I go about this ?

Comment: What is your actual goal? Do you want to use external links in your newsletter which is only sent once? Or do you want to have them defined in typoscript to be used as pages of type "external link" and in your newsletter (which is sent multiple times) at the same time?

Comment: At present the links in the newsletter are pointing to the web site. That means if the website goes down the links won't work. What I want to do is get a URL in text form and use that for a link as if I were using a constant. That way the links will continue to work whether the originating site is up or down. The URLs/links are the same for all subscribers.

Comment: Yeah, I got that but you didn't really answer my question. Why don't you just use the links to that other page directly?

Comment: Apologies, I didn't completely understand your question. If you mean the external links the idea is to enable a client to modify one of their official links (facebook, youtube...) without a technical manipulation. This solution is acceptable for internal linking. I just want to re-use those same URLs for the newsletter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use a placeholder in the rte link dialog (I assume you use the rte to write your newsletter) and then replace this placeholder in a custom hook (search for `contentPostProc-all`). There you can read your typoscript config or from any other place (own db table, csv, whatever).

You may also use the [browse link dialog hook](http://forge.typo3.org/issues/32809) to add your custom links. Take what fits best for you.